# Playframework 2.3.8 compile Less files in a module

Tags: playframework, less

I am trying compile less files in a "project-module" that has a playframework 2.3.8. I am not sure if this is possible? In other projects less files seems are compiling when I hit the url of the project.

This case is different because is not a project on its own, is a module.

Has anyone faced something similar?

One workaround is to install less from npm and compile the files with the command `lessc`.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add `.enablePlugins(SbtWeb)` at the end of your module definition in the root project. E.g.:

```
lazy val admin = (project in file("modules/admin")).enablePlugins(SbtWeb)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, was helpful. But the problem I have now, is that the module is in my local ivy repository and I can't see the less files in the project.

Comment: What does the Ivy repository look like? Just .jar?

Comment: @agusgambina I think you need to rethink this approach.